# How to change background colour depending on binding value on Windows RT

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How would I achieve this sort of effect seen below in Excel (without the grey lines) utilising a `<ListView>` control in Windows RT / Windows Store apps (assuming I have a list of integers to use as my `ItemsSource`).

In essence, I want to know the most effective way to apply a style or set background colour directly depending on what each data binding value holds.

[image: data bars]

We really need [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020306/41211). But looks like data triggers are unsupported for Windows RT apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `ItemTemplete` create rectangle, then bind its `Fill` property to your list element using below `ValueConverter`

```
public sealed class IntegerToColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 5:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
            case 10:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
            case 15:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange);
            case 25:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
            case 0:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGreen);
            default:
                return new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntegerToColorBrushConverter x:Key="IntegerToColorBrushConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IntegerToColorBrushConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>
```

Comment: I will test this today, thank you very much. This is good and would allow ultimate flexibility.. however is resorting to a programmatical approach the only way? I would prefer something which could avoid re-compiling.

Comment: Well, I don't mean to be sarcastic, but you have to write some code to make it happen this way or the other so programmatic approach is the only approach :) But seriously, I'm not aware of any other method.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase, just declaratively; meaning to avoid compiling. I don't really like specifying how my view should look based on C# code. My view/UI should whole-heartedly be declared in XAML in my opinion.

Comment: I'll accept this answer unless I hear something more in line with what I was talking about